# GitHub - Private vs Public Collaborators

Tags: git, version-control, github

New to GitHub and a bit confused by private vs public collaborators.

If I do a Micro account with one private collaborator but have 5 total team members wanting to contribute, how would the remaining four apply?  I see it has unlimited public collaborators.

So what is the difference between Private vs Public Collaborators on GitHub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have private repository and 5 collaborators, you need something bigger than Micro plan. For all private repositories you manually select collaborators in the admins tools of your repository, as you have micro plan, you can add only one collaborators to your private repository.
In other case if you have public repository, it doesn't meter which  account you have, everybody can fork and contribute to your project.

Comment: Note that the terms of the various Github plans is something that changes with time: now you have unlimited collaborators per private repo.

Answer (score 1):

The other team members can create free accounts. "5 private collaborators" means that you can add up to 5 of them to a private project.